# HttpAgilityPack Is there a way to clone the HtmlDocument

Tags: clone, html-agility-pack

I need to clone an HtmlDocument object, and I'd like to avoid serializing/deserializing.
HtmlNode has a clone (deep) capability, so I thought to clone the document node, but I have no way to recreate an HtmlDocument from a document node.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I did this (as an extension function):

```
public static HtmlDocument Clone(this HtmlDocument source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    HtmlDocument clone = new HtmlDocument();

    PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(HtmlDocument).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in infos)
    {
        if (pinfo.CanRead && pinfo.CanWrite)
        {
            pinfo.SetValue(clone, pinfo.GetValue(source));
        }
    }

    clone.DocumentNode.CopyFrom(source.DocumentNode, true);

    return clone;
 }
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comments are welcomed.